# Windows - Cannot Insert Emoji

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge, emoji

When inserting any emoji into Google Chrome, the emoji renders using the plain black/white icon.  This happens for any website, in any text box, regardless of whether it was inserted using the Windows emoji panel, or from the clipboard.

☹☹☹ - from my computer, Chrome browser

However, when loading a web page that has emojis in it, everything looks fine and colorful.

- from my phone, Chrome browser

For example, if I make a Google Calendar event with an emoji in the title using my computer, it renders in black/white, and will for any device or browser that loads it.  But if I make an event with an emoji using my phone, it renders in full design and color, and will for any device or browser that loads it.

How can I correct this behavior, so that I can enter full-color emoji when using Chrome?  I've fixed this before, but I cannot for the life of me find what I read that fixed it.  Hopefully should be able to do this without a browser extension.

**Update**:

I actually observe this behavior on multiple browsers on Windows as well, including some installed programs.  It seems that Windows is prioritizing use of text symbols over emoji, and to work around this I have to copy/paste emoji from existing places.  This seems to be an OS behavior.

Example from Edge:

[image: Text Symbol vs. Emoji Example, Google Calendar in MS Edge]

Answer (score 2):

The emoji characters render differently on different platforms: see the
[comparison chart](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html).
This depends on the operating system and the font used by the browser.

Here is a comparison of [Pizza slice](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F355/index.htm) character on the Chrome browser:

Mac: [image: Apple] Windows 7:  [image: Chrome/Win] Chrome OS: [image: Chrome/Chrome OD]

And this is the character itself, rendered by the browser you are
now using.

Google did not accept this ambiguity. Their solution was to use
an SVG font (apparently, their own).

For example, this is their rendering of the pizza slice,
as an extremely long sequence that *draws* the emoji:

```
<path fill="#333333" d="m108.990036 308.3322q0 0.96875 -0.25 2.203125q-0.09375 0.453125 -0.359375 0.75q-0.25 0.28125 -0.640625 0.5q-0.375 0.21875 -2.71875 1.078125q-2.34375 0.859375 -7.140625 2.4375l-0.953125 0.3125q-1.859375 0.59375 -2.40625 1.6875q-0.703125 1.28125 -2.125 1.28125q-0.453125 0 -0.828125 -0.15625q-0.375 -0.15625 -0.703125 -0.328125q-0.328125 -0.171875 -0.640625 -0.328125q-0.3125 -0.15625 -0.640625 -0.15625q-0.625 0 -1.015625 0.546875q-0.84375 1.125 -2.3125 1.125q-0.453125 0 -1.046875 -0.234375q-0.609375 -0.21875 -0.828125 -0.21875q-0.484375 0 -0.796875 0.515625q-0.296875 0.5 -0.359375 1.265625q-0.109375 0.875 -0.75 1.46875q-0.625 0.59375 -1.40625 0.59375q-1.4375 0 -2.125 -1.890625q-0.6875 -1.90625 -0.6875 -3.75q0 -2.34375 1.328125 -4.75q1.34375 -2.40625 4.78125 -6.78125l3.890625 -5.0q0.265625 -0.375 0.609375 -0.828125q0.34375 -0.453125 0.375 -0.9375q0.21875 -2.140625 1.34375 -3.3125q1.125 -1.171875 2.953125 -1.171875q0.90625 0 2.125 0.296875q1.21875 0.296875 2.078125 0.640625q4.890625 1.8125 8.0625 5.421875q3.1875 3.609375 3.1875 7.71875zm-16.59375 8.84375q0.59375 0 0.875 -0.53125q0.3125 -0.59375 0.765625 -1.015625q0.46875 -0.4375 1.0 -0.71875q0.53125 -0.296875 1.90625 -0.765625q2.5625 -0.828125 4.40625 -1.453125q1.859375 -0.625 3.765625 -1.34375q1.90625 -0.71875 2.078125 -0.859375q0.171875 -0.140625 0.171875 -0.265625q0.234375 -1.125 0.234375 -1.796875l-0.03125 -0.890625q-0.234375 -0.59375 -0.578125 -0.953125q-0.328125 -0.359375 -0.953125 -0.359375q-1.09375 0 -1.640625 0.625q-0.546875 0.609375 -0.546875 1.59375q0 1.28125 -1.109375 1.828125q-1.265625 0.484375 -2.5 0.703125q-1.1875 0.234375 -1.65625 0.40625q-1.375 0.53125 -2.796875 0.96875l-11.0 3.59375q-0.875 0.28125 -1.75 0.484375q-0.859375 0.203125 -1.46875 0.53125q-0.15625 0.109375 -0.296875 0.109375q-0.203125 0 -0.375 -0.15625q-0.171875 -0.15625 -0.171875 -0.421875q0 -0.703125 2.0625 -1.171875q2.515625 -0.65625 4.9375 -1.5l4.921875 -1.625q4.375 -1.421875 5.53125 -1.875q0.578125 -0.234375 1.140625 -0.3125q1.15625 -0.15625 2.09375 -0.453125q0.9375 -0.296875 1.09375 -0.453125q-0.1875 -0.859375 -0.484375 -1.59375q-0.390625 0.65625 -1.203125 1.046875q-0.8125 0.390625 -1.6875 0.390625q-1.15625 0 -1.921875 -0.59375q-0.75 -0.609375 -0.75 -1.5625l0 -0.265625l0.015625 -0.21875q0.03125 -0.4375 0.421875 -0.953125q0.390625 -0.515625 0.984375 -0.859375q0.609375 -0.34375 1.265625 -0.34375q0.515625 0 1.078125 0.15625q-1.46875 -1.84375 -3.15625 -2.796875q-1.671875 -0.96875 -3.78125 -1.234375q0.5625 0.5625 0.5625 1.453125q0 0.9375 -1.0 1.78125q-1.0 0.828125 -2.25 0.828125q-0.90625 0 -1.578125 -0.375q-0.671875 -0.390625 -0.828125 -1.09375q-1.40625 1.875 -3.09375 3.921875q1.203125 0 2.046875 0.65625q0.84375 0.65625 0.84375 1.625q0 1.0625 -0.96875 1.78125q-0.953125 0.71875 -2.15625 0.71875q-0.65625 0 -1.34375 -0.265625q-0.6875 -0.28125 -1.09375 -0.84375q-1.796875 2.71875 -2.296875 4.015625q-0.5 1.296875 -0.5 2.5625q0 1.359375 0.453125 2.796875q0.46875 1.421875 0.984375 1.421875q0.25 0 0.453125 -0.234375q0.21875 -0.234375 0.328125 -0.578125q0.25 -1.421875 0.890625 -2.21875q0.640625 -0.796875 1.640625 -0.796875q0.453125 0 1.546875 0.390625l0.328125 0.078125q0.828125 0 1.171875 -0.578125q0.828125 -1.109375 2.15625 -1.109375q0.46875 0 0.828125 0.15625q0.359375 0.15625 0.671875 0.328125q0.328125 0.171875 0.640625 0.328125q0.3125 0.15625 0.671875 0.15625zm1.140625 -21.546875q-1.21875 0 -1.984375 0.8125q-0.765625 0.796875 -0.921875 2.421875l1.78125 0.125q2.734375 0.390625 4.21875 1.03125q1.484375 0.640625 2.703125 1.71875q1.234375 1.0625 2.15625 2.390625q0.9375 1.328125 1.53125 2.8125q0.390625 -0.859375 1.125 -1.34375q0.75 -0.484375 1.625 -0.484375q0.859375 0 1.265625 0.171875q-0.609375 -1.65625 -1.96875 -3.359375q-1.34375 -1.703125 -3.34375 -3.09375q-1.984375 -1.40625 -4.34375 -2.296875q-2.359375 -0.90625 -3.84375 -0.90625zm-4.734375 14.21875q0 -0.984375 0.75 -1.53125l0.578125 -0.359375q-0.1875 -0.390625 -0.1875 -0.765625q0 -0.734375 0.609375 -1.203125q0.625 -0.484375 1.53125 -0.484375q1.609375 0 1.90625 1.25l0.453125 -0.0625q0.796875 0 1.375 0.59375q0.578125 0.578125 0.578125 1.4375q0 0.859375 -0.640625 1.390625q-0.625 0.515625 -1.609375 0.515625q-0.53125 0 -1.03125 -0.125q-0.84375 1.328125 -2.3125 1.328125q-0.859375 0 -1.421875 -0.546875q-0.546875 -0.546875 -0.578125 -1.4375zm1.75 -0.828125q-0.640625 0.28125 -0.640625 0.796875q0 0.421875 0.28125 0.65625q0.28125 0.234375 0.609375 0.234375q0.828125 0 1.359375 -0.78125q0.28125 -0.65625 0.828125 -0.65625q0.28125 0 0.609375 0.21875q0.84375 0 1.25 -0.109375q0.40625 -0.109375 0.40625 -0.65625q0 -0.375 -0.21875 -0.640625q-0.203125 -0.28125 -0.59375 -0.28125l-0.359375 0.078125q-0.203125 0.21875 -0.640625 0.21875q-0.25 0 -0.421875 -0.203125q-0.15625 -0.203125 -0.15625 -0.5l0.03125 -0.328125q0 -0.453125 -0.8125 -0.453125q-0.546875 0 -0.78125 0.21875q-0.234375 0.203125 -0.234375 0.359375q0 0.234375 0.09375 0.390625q0.46875 0.109375 0.46875 0.78125q0 0.3125 -0.203125 0.5q-0.203125 0.1875 -0.546875 0.1875l-0.328125 -0.03125z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
```

The result is: [image: Presentation mode]

This succeeds in making the emojis platform-independent, so they will
display identically on all platforms, but at the cost of losing the colors.
My own opinion that the inventor of the SVG method just missed out
on the whole idea of emojis.

Google has not implemented this "solution" in their phone software,
so the emojis created there have colors, but they will be displayed
differently on different platforms, as you can see in the above
comparison chart.

There is no way to fix this behavior in the desktop, except for
using another browser than Chrome. You may also use small
images instead of emoji sequences in some cases.

([source](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/87968/12608))

Comment: I notice this behavior on multiple browsers though, running on Windows.  When inserting an emoji from `Win + ;`, Windows will prioritize using a text symbol instead of the emoji.  I see this behavior on Chrome, Edge, Firefox, and even some installed programs like MS Word.

Comment: I agree with OP; using another browser is not a solution, and I don't think the answer correctly diagnoses the problem. This situation is distinct from the one presented in the source, which was about a specific website.